# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\musicalia\login.php on line 19

Tags: php, mysqli, login

No entiendo porque me aparece este error, soy bastante noob en código `php` así que no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. Mi intención es que un usuario haga `login` y en caso de no estar registrado o meter mal la contraseña, que se diga.

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "equipamentos";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn)
{
    die("No hay conexión: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST["usuario"];
$pass = $_POST["contrasinal"];

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '".$nombre);
$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE contrasinal = '".$pass);
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$rn = mysqli_num_rows($quer);
if($nr == 1 && $rn==1)
{
    //header("Location: pagina.html")
    echo "Bienvenido:" .$nombre;
}
else if ($nr == 0)
{
    //header("Location: registro.html");
    echo "No registrado"; 
}
else{
  echo "contraseña incorrecta";
}



?>
```

Comment: Tus dos consultas tienen error de sintaxis, no cierras la comilla simple ni la comilla doble. Prueba así: `$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '$nombre'");` y así: `$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE contrasinal = '$pass'");`

Answer (score 1):

Tus dos consultas tienen error de sintaxis, no cierras la comilla simple ni la comilla doble. Si pruebas así, debería funcionar:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '$nombre'");
$quer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE contrasinal = '$pass'");
```

Además, puedes escribir una sola consulta que verifique los dos criterios:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM novo_rexistro WHERE usuario = '$nombre' AND contrasinal = '$pass'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($nr > 0)
{
    //header("Location: pagina.html")
    echo "Bienvenido:" .$nombre;
}
else 
{
    //header("Location: registro.html");
    echo "No registrado"; 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero necesito que cuando el error sea de contraseña que indique que es un error de contraseña, y si en cambio el error es de no registro del usuario que indique que hay que registrar al usuario

Comment: @Antia OK. En ese caso el problema debería resolverse corrigiendo el error de sintaxis en la consulta, como se explica al principio de la respuesta. Deberías considerar también el uso de consultas preparadas para evitar ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Ya he sido capaz de solucionarlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)